# Algorithm to organise calendar events using minimum positions

Tags: algorithm

I want to build an algorithm that organizes calendar events to display positions.

Each event looks like this:

```
{
  title: 'A Title',
  start: aDate,
  end: anotherDate,
  position: aNumber
}
```

I want to achieve a layout similar to this

(A & B have position 0, C & D position 1 and E position 2) or any other combination, but not use more positions than necessary.

[image]

Can anyone suggest witch algorithm might do the trick of automatically assigning suitable positions to my events? (Name reference or pseudocode would be a lot of help)

My thoughts up till now are to keep track in the event object the other overlapping events and then somehow compare their positions / overlaps if any to get the number, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Assigning a swimlane to each event, so that no two events overlap on the same swimlane, and the total number of swimlanes is minimized, is already an interesting problem. Finding space for the labels further complicates that, so I would simplify it to ignore the labels for now.

Comment: The labels are ignored. It is just for reference with the comment right above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given several existing free lanes where you can place an event, any of them is an acceptable choice, in the sense that the total maximum number of required lanes will not be affected. Given no free lanes, there is only one choice: add a new lane.

Therefore, the problem is actually very simple: just place an event in the first free lane that you can find (or create a new one if none is currently free), and keep track of the lanes that are occupied and the times when they will be freed up.

This greedy approach could look as follows:

```
initialize a list of free lanes
for each event e,
   1. check which occupied lanes are free for e.startTime
   2. assign e.lane to a free lane, or add a new free lane if none empty
   3. mark the e.lane as occupied until e.endTime is reached
```

Step 2 can stick to the lowest-number free lane (to yield a more top-compact representation), or to spread lanes out a bit (which may make aesthetic sense, although you will not know the total number of lanes required until after a 1st pass).

In any case, the algorithm only requires one pass, and minimal additional memory (keeping track of which lanes are occupied until what times).